# Append rows to a dataframe efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': ['1642847484', '1642847484', '1642847484', '1642847484', '1642847487', '1642847487','1642847487','1642847487','1642847487','1642847487','1642847487','1642847487', '1642847489', '1642847489', '1642847489'],
                   'value': [11, 10, 14, 20, 3, 2, 9, 48, 5, 20, 12, 20, 56, 12, 8]})
```

I need to do some operations on each group of values with the same timestamp , so I use groupBy as follows :

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('Timestamp')
```

And then iterate over the rows of each group and append the results row by row in a new dataframe:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(columns=( 'Timestamp', 'value'))
for group_name, df_group in df_grouped:
    i = 0
    for row_index, row in df_group.iterrows():
        row['Timestamp'] = row['Timestamp']* 1000  + i * 30
        df_out = df_out.append(row)
        i = i+1
    print(df_out.tail())
```

But my approach takes so much time (7M+ rows ) and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do so . Thank you

Comment: there is no efficiency when using `iterrows` why don't you explain what you try to achieve?

Comment: I need to add a fraction of time to the rows in each group , without touching the borders of the group

Comment: @LOR13 `I need to add a fraction of time to the rows in each group` - can you be more specific?

Comment: Since speed is your concern, knowing what `...` is would allow for benchmarking answers.

Comment: I need to add a 30 milliseconds step to all the rows except for the first one of the group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `itterows` here is not necessary, you can use:

```
def f(x):

    x['Timestamp'] = ...
    ....
    return x
    
df1 = df.groupby('Timestamp').apply(f)
```

EDIT: Create counter `Series` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), multiple and add to `Timestamp`:

```
#if necessary
df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].astype(np.int64)

df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'] * 1000 + df.groupby('Timestamp').cumcount() * 30
print(df)
        Timestamp  value
0   1642847484000     11
1   1642847484030     10
2   1642847484060     14
3   1642847484090     20
4   1642847487000      3
5   1642847487030      2
6   1642847487060      9
7   1642847487090     48
8   1642847487120      5
9   1642847487150     20
10  1642847487180     12
11  1642847487210     20
12  1642847489000     56
13  1642847489030     12
14  1642847489060      8
```